# How the sum of a string array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, sum

I need to write a program that can compute a string that consists of weights and their units such as that one: "10, kg, 500, g, 0.5, t" into the total sum of the weights. It has to convert the different weights into kilograms first, though. This is what i got so far for converting the grams but it doesn't work. I am using C.

```
double total_weight_kg(String s) {         
    Array a = sa_of_string(s);
    Array w = da_of_string(s);
    double gram = 0;
    int n = a_length(a);     
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {       
        if (i == 'g') {
            gram += get(double, w, i = i - 1);
        }
    }
    return gram * 0.001;
 }
```

Comment: `if (i == 'g') ` inside loop is totally non sense....

Comment: what is t? tonne??

Comment: Yes, t stands for tons.

Comment: @NoIdea: Can you give some other example string which you are going to use?

Comment: it should work with any string of this format: "double, unit". Here are a few examples: "9, kg, 8, g, 0.2, t, 733, g, 1, t, 17.5, kg" or "0.1, g, 9.7, kg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If string format is be fixed you can use sscanf() to read values from it.

```
double total_weight_kg(String s) {
    double        kg = 0.0;
    double        g  = 0.0;
    double        t  = 0.0;

    //Assuming "<kg_val>, kg, <g_val>, g, <t_val>, t" format.
    sscanf("%lf, kg, %lf, g, %lf, t", &kg, &g, &t);

    kg += (g/1000.0) + (t*1000.0);

    return kg;
}
```

**Update1:**
I saw [this conversion](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#q=ton%20to%20tonne). To be clear in my answer i assumed "tonne" and not "ton". For "ton", you can use this program.

```
double total_weight_kg(String s) {
    double        kg = 0.0;
    double        g  = 0.0;
    double        t  = 0.0;

    //Assuming "<kg_val>, kg, <g_val>, g, <t_val>, t" format.
    sscanf("%lf, kg, %lf, g, %lf, t", &kg, &g, &t);

    kg += (g/1000.0) + (t*907.185);

    return kg;
}
```

**Update2**
If I have to add weights in a string like "9, kg, 8, g, 0.2, t, 733, g, 1, t, 17.5, kg" or "0.1, g, 9.7, kg", I would use the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

double total_weight_kg(char* s) 
{
    double        kg             = 0.0;
    double        wieght_val     = 0.0; //If you want to use array, make this an array, store value in diff indices and add them at the end.
    char          wieght_unit[4] = ""; //Max string is "kg,".
    char          *str           = s;


    while(0 < strlen(str))
    {
        sscanf(str, "%lf, %s,", &wieght_val, wieght_unit);
        printf("Read: %lf, %s\n", wieght_val, wieght_unit);

        if(!strcmp(wieght_unit, "kg,") || !strcmp(wieght_unit, "kg"))
            kg += wieght_val;
        else if(!strcmp(wieght_unit, "g,") || !strcmp(wieght_unit, "g"))
            kg += wieght_val / 1000.0;
        else if(!strcmp(wieght_unit, "t,") || !strcmp(wieght_unit, "t"))
            kg += wieght_val * 1000.0; //OR 907.185

        //Update string pointer.
        str = strstr(str, wieght_unit);
        str += strlen(wieght_unit);

        //Resetting values.
        strcpy( wieght_unit, "");
        wieght_val = 0.0;
    }

    return kg;
}

int main() {

    printf("Weight is %lf kg\n", total_weight_kg("9, kg, 8, g, 0.2, t, 733, g, 1, t, 17.5, kg"));

    return 1;
}
```

Output:

```
Read: 9.000000, kg,                                                                                                                             
Read: 8.000000, g,                                                                                                                              
Read: 0.200000, t,                                                                                                                              
Read: 733.000000, g,                                                                                                                            
Read: 1.000000, t,                                                                                                                              
Read: 17.500000, kg                                                                                                                             
Weight is 1227.241000 kg
```

Comment: _tring that consists of weights and their units **such as that one**: "10, kg, 500, g, 0.5, t"_....your code works only for the proposed example, it isn't a workable/usable solution...

Comment: I assume the question is about the string with weights in that format. Also, I have clearly mentioned it in my answer.

Comment: First of all thank you for the answer. I have to use arrays in this exercise ,though.

Comment: @LPs: I have a solution (Update3). I think it is not as optimised as yours. But it works.

Comment: @NoIdea: Can you test the function in Update2? Please note String type is not valid in C. You have to use char*.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I didn't have to use stardard C in my last task so I didn't quiet get what you did there. But now I have a similar task with standard C and your code works perfectly. Thank you very much! I have a question though. Why do you have to use !strcmp with the exclamation mark?

Comment: @NoIdea: strcmp() compares two strings and return 0 if they are same and a non-zero value if they are different. In C, 0 is considered false and non-zero is considered as true if they are used in a condition statement. Also, '!' is boolean NOT. I wanted to execute something if strings were same. so I used if(!strcmp()), which will be true if strings are same: Read more here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the man of used library](http://hci.uni-hannover.de/files/prog1lib/string__array_8h.html#afce905269828bedb2e4daffe1c0ad10d), something like the following code should work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{   
   if ((i%2) != 0)
   {
      if (strcmp(sa_get(w,i), "g") == 0) 
      {
         gram += get(double, w, i - 1);
      }
   } 
}
```

**CODE IS NOT TESTED**

Comment: _doesn't work_ doesn't giveì me information: WhatsApp wrong?